# Verifying if worksheet checkbox's height is enough for the caption

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to know if there is a way to know if the checkbox's height is sufficient for the whole caption to show. For example:

[image]

In the above picture, both checkboxes have the same text but the height of the one on the left was simply not enough for the whole caption to show. Is there a way to verify this with VBA?

I can verify the height with `Feuil1.CheckBoxes("chbx_1").height` and change the caption with `Feuil1.CheckBoxes("chbx_1").caption` but that doesn't tell me that the caption is showing.

Note; this is not an ActiveX checkbox and I do not wish to use one. I also don't want to use a form.

Comment: In the past I've found this not to be possible, but there is a workaround as such, use a character that is more than enough, say a capitalised o, in a hidden label, then use this a reference height.  then if a.height<hidden.height will give you an approx. answer, I've used O and D, there may be others.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I was hoping not to resort to that but I'll do it if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

I may be corrected but I am not aware of any way to definitively ensure it is all showing.

I am suggesting a method I have implemented on UserForms that may work on Worksheets too. The method involves dynamic sizing of the controls to maximise the screen space available, this works for me when dealing with different screen sizes and Mac/PC differences.

Consider adapting the below to work for your content:-

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Name = "Feuil1" Then FormatForm
End Sub

Private Sub FormatForm()
Dim WkSht   As Worksheet
Set WkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
    WkSht.CheckBoxes(1).Top = WkSht.Range("B2").Top
    WkSht.CheckBoxes(1).Left = WkSht.Range("B2").Left
    WkSht.CheckBoxes(1).Width = WkSht.Range("B2:C2").Width
    WkSht.CheckBoxes(1).Height = WkSht.Range("B2:B3").Height
Set WkSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

This was placed in the VBA projects `ThisWorkbook`. In the above example `FormatForm` is called and is used to adjust the size of the checkbox to cover range `B2:C3`. If your Worksheet is quite design heavy this could be a solution to ensure you make the most of the screen space available.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but unfortunately not applicable to my case. Every time the worksheet is opened, the code deletes all checkboxes and according to a list in a database, recreates the required checkboxes. Sometimes the caption will be long, sometimes short, but I can't know how many checkboxes will be created and I want to use as few lines as possible.

Comment: Maybe set their height/width to be big enough for double lines in all cases as the checkboxes are created? that would only be two more lines.

Comment: I thought about it, but it would take too much space. I have up to 20+ checkboxes right now and sometimes it goes into triple lines, but the majority of the times it stays within 1 line. it would look ridiculous if everything was made for triples!